# How to mask all characters in this string in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I am parameterising some code by having case when statements as macro variables that are then later injected into another macro. I therefore need to convert the strings into global variables, but am struggling to get everything masked. A simplified version of my code looks like so:

```
%macro test();

%let x_var = 

case when var = 'Red' then 1
when var = 'Black***' then 2
when var = 'Deep Purple' then 3
else 4
end as var_sort

;

%global var = %nrbquote(&x_reg.);

%mend;

%test;
```

...however, that is failing to mask everything as I am receiving log errors of the order:

```
ERROR: Invalid symbolic variable name =.
ERROR: Invalid symbolic variable name =.
ERROR: Invalid symbolic variable name '.
ERROR: Invalid symbolic variable name '.
ERROR: Invalid symbolic variable name 1.
```

Can anyone advise on a fix, please? I always get confused a bit when trying to mask special characters as to which is the correct method to use.

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in X_VAR that needs masking.

Comment: You create a macro variable called `x_var`, and then use `x_reg` for the global macro variable? Also, a format may help instead of case/if then logic. It's more straightforward and no macro needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%global` statement is used to define a macro variable (symbol). If you want to assign it a value then use a `%let` statement.

```
%global var ;
%let var = %nrbquote(&x_reg.);
```

If you want to set `var` to literally `&_rx_reg.` then use a data step.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('var','&x_reg.','g');
run;
```